# SVG Анимация вращения группы вокруг своего центра

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

У меня есть изображение SVG, которое содержит группу кругов и текстовую группу. Круговая группа состоит из нескольких точек. Эта группа кругов должна вращаться вокруг одного своего центра круга, но она продолжает вращаться вокруг верхнего левого угла SVG. Чтобы решить эту проблему, я пробовал многое, но мне не удалось изменить центр вращения этого круга.

Итак, мой вопрос: как я могу определить центр вращения группы изображений SVG, не меняя положение групп?

```css
svg {
 width: 50%;
}

/* Rotate around the circle center */

#Circleelement {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: rotate; 
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: rotate; 
    animation-duration: 2s; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;

}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}





/* _x31_ */
#_x31_, #_x32_7, #_x33_1, #_x31_3 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 3s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 3s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 3s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 3s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x32_ */
#_x32_, #_x32_8, #_x32_3, #_x31_0 {
 animation: flickerAnimation 9s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 9s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 9s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 9s infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.5s;    
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x3_ */
#_x33_, #_x33_2, #_x32_5, #_x31_7 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 13s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 13s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 13s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 13s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0.75s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.75s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.75s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.75s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x34_ */
#_x34_, #_x32_4, #_x33_6, #_x33_5, #_x31_5 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 23s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 23s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 23s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 23s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x35_ */
#_x35_, #_x32_2, #_x33_0, #_x31_9 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 15s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 15s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 15s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 15s infinite;
 animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x36_ */
#_x36_, #_x32_0, #_x32_9, #_x31_1 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 18s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 18s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 18s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 18s infinite;
 animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1.5s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x37_ */
#_x37_, #_x33_4, #_x31_2 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 6s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 6s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 6s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 6s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.5s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x38_ */
#_x38_, #_x32_6, #_x31_6 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.2s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x39_ */
#_x39_, #_x33_3, #_x31_4 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 25s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 25s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 25s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 25s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.8s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x31_0 */
#_x31_0, #_x32_1, #_x31_8 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 30s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 30s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 30s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 30s infinite;
 animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 2s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<body>
<svg version="1.1" id="Logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Circleelement" transform="translate(150 170) rotate(45) translate(-150 -170)">
 <circle id="_x31_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="242.5" cy="81.5" r="11.1">  </circle>
 <circle id="_x32_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="277.1" cy="87" r="10.8"/>
 <circle id="_x33_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="307.5" cy="102" r="10.5"/>
 <circle id="_x34_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="332.1" cy="124.9" r="10.2"/>
 <circle id="_x35_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="349.1" cy="154.2" r="9.9"/>
 <circle id="_x36_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="357" cy="188.1" r="9.6"/>
 <circle id="_x37_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="354.3" cy="223.4" r="9.4"/>
 <circle id="_x38_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="341.7" cy="255.1" r="9.1"/>
 <circle id="_x39_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="320.7" cy="281.4" r="8.8"/>
 <circle id="_x31_0" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="293.1" cy="300.6" r="8.5"/>
 <circle id="_x31_1" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="260.3" cy="311.1" r="8.2"/>
 <circle id="_x31_2" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="224.7" cy="311.3" r="7.9"/>
 <circle id="_x31_3" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="191.8" cy="301.2" r="7.6"/>
 <circle id="_x31_4" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="164" cy="282.3" r="7.3"/>
 <circle id="_x31_5" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="142.7" cy="256.3" r="7"/>
 <circle id="_x31_6" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="129.7" cy="224.7" r="6.8"/>
 <circle id="_x31_7" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="126.6" cy="189.4" r="6.5"/>
 <circle id="_x31_8" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="134" cy="155.5" r="6.2"/>
 <circle id="_x31_9" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="150.7" cy="126.1" r="5.9"/>
 <circle id="_x32_0" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="174.9" cy="102.9" r="5.6"/>
 <circle id="_x32_1" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="205.2" cy="87.5" r="5.3"/>
 <circle id="_x32_2" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="242.6" cy="123.6" r="10.4"/>
 <circle id="_x32_3" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="282.5" cy="136.5" r="9.7"/>
 <circle id="_x32_4" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="308.8" cy="168" r="9.1"/>
 <circle id="_x32_5" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="314" cy="210.3" r="8.4"/>
 <circle id="_x32_6" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="261.1" cy="269.4" r="7.1"/>
 <circle id="_x32_7" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="218.3" cy="268.8" r="6.5"/>
 <circle id="_x32_8" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="184.1" cy="246.1" r="5.8"/>
 <circle id="_x32_9" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="167.1" cy="208.3" r="5.2"/>
 <circle id="_x33_0" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="200.5" cy="135.4" r="3.9"/>
 <circle id="_x33_1" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="242.2" cy="164.1" r="5.4"/>
 <circle id="_x33_2" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="271.9" cy="181.8" r="4.8"/>
 <circle id="_x33_3" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="271.5" cy="216.9" r="4.1"/>
 <circle id="_x33_4" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="241.3" cy="233.9" r="3.5"/>
 <circle id="_x33_5" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="211.4" cy="216.5" r="2.8"/>
 <circle id="_x33_6" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="211.4" cy="181.4" r="2.2"/>
</g>
<g id="Name">
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 44 439.7)" font-family="'Gotham-Book'" font-size="54">S O M E T E X T</text>
</g>
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/30268311/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Вы также можете обойти любые проблемы браузера с `transform-origin`, используя вложенные группы.

```
<g transform="translate(243.35 194.85)">
<g id="Circleelement">
<g transform="translate(-243.35 -194.85)">
```

Таким образом, вращение CSS работает с группой, которая,  центрирована на `origin`. Таким образом, элемент остается на месте.

```css
svg {
 width: 50%;
}

/* Rotate around the circle center */

#Circleelement {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: rotate; 
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: rotate; 
    animation-duration: 2s; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;

}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}





/* _x31_ */
#_x31_, #_x32_7, #_x33_1, #_x31_3 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 3s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 3s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 3s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 3s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x32_ */
#_x32_, #_x32_8, #_x32_3, #_x31_0 {
 animation: flickerAnimation 9s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 9s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 9s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 9s infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.5s;    
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x3_ */
#_x33_, #_x33_2, #_x32_5, #_x31_7 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 13s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 13s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 13s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 13s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0.75s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.75s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.75s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.75s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x34_ */
#_x34_, #_x32_4, #_x33_6, #_x33_5, #_x31_5 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 23s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 23s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 23s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 23s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x35_ */
#_x35_, #_x32_2, #_x33_0, #_x31_9 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 15s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 15s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 15s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 15s infinite;
 animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x36_ */
#_x36_, #_x32_0, #_x32_9, #_x31_1 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 18s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 18s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 18s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 18s infinite;
 animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1.5s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x37_ */
#_x37_, #_x33_4, #_x31_2 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 6s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 6s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 6s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 6s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.5s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x38_ */
#_x38_, #_x32_6, #_x31_6 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.2s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x39_ */
#_x39_, #_x33_3, #_x31_4 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 25s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 25s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 25s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 25s infinite;
 animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.8s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

/* _x31_0 */
#_x31_0, #_x32_1, #_x31_8 {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 30s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 30s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 30s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 30s infinite;
 animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 2s; 
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<body>
<svg version="1.1" id="Logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
<g transform="translate(243.35 194.85)">
<g id="Circleelement">
<g transform="translate(-243.35 -194.85)">
 <circle id="_x31_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="242.5" cy="81.5" r="11.1">  </circle>
 <circle id="_x32_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="277.1" cy="87" r="10.8"/>
 <circle id="_x33_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="307.5" cy="102" r="10.5"/>
 <circle id="_x34_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="332.1" cy="124.9" r="10.2"/>
 <circle id="_x35_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="349.1" cy="154.2" r="9.9"/>
 <circle id="_x36_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="357" cy="188.1" r="9.6"/>
 <circle id="_x37_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="354.3" cy="223.4" r="9.4"/>
 <circle id="_x38_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="341.7" cy="255.1" r="9.1"/>
 <circle id="_x39_" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="320.7" cy="281.4" r="8.8"/>
 <circle id="_x31_0" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="293.1" cy="300.6" r="8.5"/>
 <circle id="_x31_1" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="260.3" cy="311.1" r="8.2"/>
 <circle id="_x31_2" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="224.7" cy="311.3" r="7.9"/>
 <circle id="_x31_3" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="191.8" cy="301.2" r="7.6"/>
 <circle id="_x31_4" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="164" cy="282.3" r="7.3"/>
 <circle id="_x31_5" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="142.7" cy="256.3" r="7"/>
 <circle id="_x31_6" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="129.7" cy="224.7" r="6.8"/>
 <circle id="_x31_7" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="126.6" cy="189.4" r="6.5"/>
 <circle id="_x31_8" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="134" cy="155.5" r="6.2"/>
 <circle id="_x31_9" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="150.7" cy="126.1" r="5.9"/>
 <circle id="_x32_0" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="174.9" cy="102.9" r="5.6"/>
 <circle id="_x32_1" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="205.2" cy="87.5" r="5.3"/>
 <circle id="_x32_2" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="242.6" cy="123.6" r="10.4"/>
 <circle id="_x32_3" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="282.5" cy="136.5" r="9.7"/>
 <circle id="_x32_4" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="308.8" cy="168" r="9.1"/>
 <circle id="_x32_5" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="314" cy="210.3" r="8.4"/>
 <circle id="_x32_6" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="261.1" cy="269.4" r="7.1"/>
 <circle id="_x32_7" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="218.3" cy="268.8" r="6.5"/>
 <circle id="_x32_8" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="184.1" cy="246.1" r="5.8"/>
 <circle id="_x32_9" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="167.1" cy="208.3" r="5.2"/>
 <circle id="_x33_0" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="200.5" cy="135.4" r="3.9"/>
 <circle id="_x33_1" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="242.2" cy="164.1" r="5.4"/>
 <circle id="_x33_2" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="271.9" cy="181.8" r="4.8"/>
 <circle id="_x33_3" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="271.5" cy="216.9" r="4.1"/>
 <circle id="_x33_4" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="241.3" cy="233.9" r="3.5"/>
 <circle id="_x33_5" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="211.4" cy="216.5" r="2.8"/>
 <circle id="_x33_6" fill="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="211.4" cy="181.4" r="2.2"/>
</g>
</g>
</g>
<g id="Name">
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 44 439.7)" font-family="'Gotham-Book'" font-size="54">S O M E T E X T</text>
</g>
</svg>
</body>
```

[<sub>@PaulLeBeau</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272136/6571020)